# How can I jump between methods of a super and sub class?

Tags: c#

If I have a class that acts like a state machine, Foo like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual State Update()
    {
        switch (CurrentState)
        {
            case State.Start:
                if (!WatingForData())
                    CurrentState = State.GotData;
                break;
            case State.GotData:
                if (something else)
                    ....
                break;
        }

        return CurrentState;
    }
}
```

Which handle general steps.

And a derived class Bar will have yet another state machine for individual steps
like so:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override State Update()
    {
        switch (CurrentState)
        {
            case State.GetData:
                if (GotData())
                    CurrentState = State.GotData;
                break;
            case State.GotData:
                if (ProcessData())
                    CurrentState = base.State.GotData;
                break;
        }

        return CurrentState;
    }
}
```

I would like to achieve something like this;

```
while(!Foo.State == State.Done)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    Foo.Update()
}
```

Where the program first goes to Bar.Update() and handle all the individual (sub) steps and when done proceeds to Foo.Update().

Given my current code I would have to change Foo's State to new (instead of virtual) and do something like;

```
while(!Foo.State == State.Done)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    if(Bar.State == Bar.State.Done)
    {
        ((Foo)Bar).Update()
    }
    else
    {
        Foo.Update();    
    }
}
```

Not sure how I can do this in a cleaner way.
I would like to know if there are a better ways to handle state machines with sub states?
Examples would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why not just have `Bar.Update()` call `base.Update()` as either the first or the last command in the method.  This will cause `Foo.Update()` to be chained through the child class `Bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just change your `Bar.Update` to call the `base.Update`:

```
public override State Update()
{
    // sub steps:
    switch (CurrentState)
    {
        case State.GetData:
            if (GotData())
                CurrentState = State.GotData;
            break;
        case State.GotData:
            if (ProcessData())
                CurrentState = base.State.GotData;
            break;
    }

    // proceed to Foo.Update:
    return base.Update();
}
```

Comment: Yes, just call the base.Update() after the super implementation.

Comment: Wow, how did I not see that? thanks. I did however change State to return void and added another state called Done. now it calls base.Update() when the program is in the done state of the sub step.